# Showing $\frac{y-x}{\cos{x}}(2+\sin{x}\frac{\cos{x}+\cos{y}+\cos{x}\cos{y}}{\sin{(y-x)}})\leq \pi $

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I was playing around a bit with trigonometric inequalities and found this: 
$$\frac{y-x}{\cos{x}}(2+\sin{x}\frac{\cos{x}+\cos{y}+\cos{x}\cos{y}}{\sin{(y-x)}})\leq \pi
$$
for $0\leq x<y \leq\pi/2$.

This can be checked on Matlab for example. I know it's not the prettiest of inequalities but I found it interesting that the value $\pi$ is achieved for the pair $(x,y)= (0,\pi/2)$ and thought there could be some elegant way to show it.

I have tried various approaches with no luck. I think one promising approach is to show that the function is increasing with respect to $y$ when we fix $x$ but I found the calculations to be quite messy. I would appreciate any ideas on proving this.

Comment: Does the source of the problem reveal the existence of elegant solutions? For example, contest inequalities often admit elegant solutions.

Comment: @RiverLi I have no source for this other than myself. So maybe there is no elegant solution. I just feel there should be (or at least something not too complicated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Fact 1*: It holds that $z \le \frac{\pi \sin z}{2 + \cos z}$ for $z\in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

From Fact 1, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{\pi \sin (y-x)}{2 + \cos (y-x)}\frac{1}{\cos x}\Big(2 + \sin x \frac{\cos x + \cos y + \cos x \cos y}{\sin (y-x)}\Big) \le \pi$$
which is equivalent to
$$[\cos^2 x + (1-\cos x)\sin x]\cos y + (2-\sin x)(1-\sin y)\cos x \ge 0.$$
Clearly, it is true. We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

*Proof of Fact 1*: It suffices to prove that $\pi \sin z - z \cos z - 2 z \ge 0$ for $z \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Let $f(z) = \pi \sin z - z \cos z - 2 z$.

We have
$f'(z) = \pi \cos z - \cos z + z\sin z - 2$, $f''(z) = -\pi \sin z + 2 \sin z + z\cos z $
and $f'''(z) = -\pi \cos z + 3 \cos z - z \sin z$.

Clearly, $f'''(z) < 0$ for $z \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.
Also, $f''(0) = 0$. Thus, $f''(z) \le 0$ for $z \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.
Thus, $f(z)$ is concave on $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Since $f(0) = f(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 0$, we have, for $z \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$,
$$f(z) = f\Big((1-\tfrac{z}{\pi/2})\cdot 0 + \tfrac{z}{\pi/2} \cdot \tfrac{\pi}{2}\Big)
\ge (1-\tfrac{z}{\pi/2})f(0) + \tfrac{z}{\pi/2} f(\tfrac{\pi}{2}) = 0.$$ 
We are done.

Comment: Wow! I didn't think this would be answered. It's what I was looking for. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: @JT45  You are welcome.